# How to handle missing data with respect to type of dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where has column **types** that has type like `Primary` , `Secondary`.

> df

```
   ID    types        C   D
0  101   Primary      2   3
1  103   Primary      6   3
2  108   Primary     10   ?
3  109   Primary      3  12
4  118   Secondary    5   2
5  122   Secondary    ?   6
6  123   Secondary    5   6
7  125   Secondary    2   5
```

I want to replace missing value with `median` for each type. Such as-

> result_df

```
   ID    types        C   D
0  101   Primary      2   3
1  103   Primary      6   3
2  108   Primary     10   3
3  109   Primary      3  12
4  118   Secondary    5   2
5  122   Secondary    5   6
6  123   Secondary    5   6
7  125   Secondary    2   5
```

How can do it with Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

First replace `?` in your df with actual `np.nan` values:

```
In [1268]: df = df.replace('?',np.nan)
In [1273]: df
Out[1273]: 
    ID      types    C    D
0  101    Primary    2    3
1  103    Primary    6    3
2  108    Primary   10  NaN
3  109    Primary    3   12
4  118  Secondary    5    2
5  122  Secondary  NaN    6
6  123  Secondary    5    6
7  125  Secondary    2    5
```

> **For me the `dtypes` is showing as `object` for columns `C` and `D`. Hence, I convert these into numeric before finding median. If this is
>   not applicable for you, skip this step and directly run the below
>   command with `transform` function.**

```
In [1274]: df.dtypes
Out[1274]: 
ID        int64
types    object
C        object
D        object
dtype: object
```

In order to find `median`, convert columns `C` and `D` into pandas numeric type:

```
In [1256]: df.C = df.C.apply(pd.to_numeric)
In [1258]: df.D = df.D.apply(pd.to_numeric)

In [1279]: df.dtypes
Out[1279]: 
ID         int64
types     object
C        float64
D        float64
dtype: object
```

Now, you can fill nulls with `median` of types in both columns `C` and `D` like below, using `groupby` and `transform` functions:

```
In [1265]: df.C = df.C.fillna(df.groupby('types')['C'].transform('median'))

In [1266]: df.D = df.D.fillna(df.groupby('types')['D'].transform('median'))

In [1267]: df
Out[1267]: 
    ID      types     C     D
0  101    Primary   2.0   3.0
1  103    Primary   6.0   3.0
2  108    Primary  10.0   3.0
3  109    Primary   3.0  12.0
4  118  Secondary   5.0   2.0
5  122  Secondary   5.0   6.0
6  123  Secondary   5.0   6.0
7  125  Secondary   2.0   5.0
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Mayank Porwal, first convert the missing values into np.nan and then you can apply imputation with [sklearn impute](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html) methods.

[simpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df.replace('?',np.nan,inplace=True)

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

for types,group in df.groupby('types'):
    imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median')
    df.loc[df['types']==types,['C','D']] = imp.fit_transform(group[['C','D']])
```